# Optimization in SciPy with noisy loss function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, tensorflow

I have a nasty optimization problem in TensorFlow which requires a non-linear optimizer to solve, the internal tensorflow optimizers (Gradient Descent, AdaGrad, Adam) seem to do significantly worse than using scipy as an external optimizer (CG, BFGS) of the same graph.

This would be fine but for the production run I want to do I need to use minibatches of my training dataset to optimize. I have implemented this by each time the loss/gradient function is called, a new minibatch of data is used to calculate it. (I am using a modified version of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py )  In practice, this means that the loss function is a noisy function of the input parameters.

Scipy seems to be having a problem with this, limiting any calling of scipy.minimize to only a few iterations, like so:

```
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
     Current function value: 71.329124
     Iterations: 2
     Function evaluations: 28
     Gradient evaluations: 16
```

In contrast, if I run this optimization with the full dataset (which is feasible now but not later) it will converge to around 0.1 within one call of scipy.minimize (and do around 1000 iterations without quitting).

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a fix (easy preferred but hacky also OK) to stop scipy from quitting out of these optimization problems? Something like a min_iter keyword would be perfect but as far as I'm aware that isn't implemented.

I hope this made sense. Thanks!

EDIT: I was asked for code but the full code is several hundreds of lines long so I'll make a short example:

```
...
def minibatch_loss_function(model, inputs, outputs, batch_size=10):
    minibatch_mask=random.choice(range(0, len(inputs), batch_size)
    minib_inputs=inputs[minibatch_mask]
    minib_outputs=outputs[minibatch_mask]
    return loss(model, minib_inputs, minib_outputs), 
               gradients(model, minib_inputs, minib_outputs)

...

training_input, training_output = training_data(n_examples)
scp.optimize.minimize(minibatch_loss_function, 
     args={'inputs': training_input, 'outputs': training_output)
```

Comment: There is a reason the optimizer is quitting with that warning. Forcing to continue with more iterations will just break everything (worse loss, infinite loss, breaking constraints...). I'm a bit scared theory-wise and see no code to reason about what you are doing exactly.

Comment: @sascha I think the reason it is quitting with that warning is because the value of the loss from one iteration to the next is increasing due to noise fluctuations, where the true mean of the loss is still decreasing. Therefore although the optimization may be working it is quitting out prematurely.

Comment: What make you think these algorithms are suited for this? And there is still no code shown. Try a gradient-free algorithm like fmin or fmin_powell.

Comment: @sascha I have added some code in an edit, hope this helps illustrate what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Well you can obviously start to try different algorithms and not stick to the defaults (which i can't anticipate here). But i don't see any optimizer from scipy.optimize help you with this problem. The gradient-free ones might work somewhat, but i would be scared about numerical-issues in all other optimizers as line-searches and co. probably go mad with such a noisy model. (Maybe it would be just more clever to rent a high-memory machine and stick to batch-mode algorithms; probably L-BFGS).

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the discussion, I see your point about the line-searches

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing the coefficients or variables in a preprocessing step could help. Did you do that?   Overflow, underflow, and failure to converge are commonly a symptom of numerical scaling problems.